# How to use variables loaded from configuration files (acces by fields of static obejct or copy it )?

Tags: java, oop

What is faster (and better) ? :

1. Load variables to a special
   static object and when a variable
   from configuration file is needed
   get variale from static object's
   field.
2. Copy configuration
   variable to a local field when
   creating new object which needs a
   configuration variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer instance level myself, as long as you aren't doing it excessively (i.e. Don't read the configuration every time you instantiate something).

Static configurations will give you heartache. Especially for testing.

The best solution in my mind is to use a framework like Spring (or Guice) to inject configuration type information into your objects.

Comment: "Static configurations will give you heartache. Especially for testing." Could You explain what you mean?

Comment: It has to do with dependency injection. Presumably, if you have a static configuration, at some point you will have a static method to access it. That static method cannot be mocked out or overridden during testing. Yes, there are ways around that. However, it's usually easier to inject some sort of a non-static configuration with a dependency injection container. Once you enable that, you'll be able to inject configurations during testing.

Comment: Also, do a bit of googling for unit testing and statics. You will find a lot of documentation on statics being evil, or difficult to test. My experience has mirrored that repeatedly. Including the static configuration problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say use on-demand caching. Look at the [**MapMaker** from guava-collections](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html). If you doesn't want to add additional dependency then I'd prefer option 1.

Answer (score 1):

I would abstract the configuration with an interface and provide strategies like:

```
public interface Config {
   public String getUrl();
   public String getName();
}

public class PropertiesConfig implements Config {

   private final String url;
   private final String name;

   public PropertiesConfig(String filepath) {
       Properties props = // read properties from file input stream
       this.url = props.getProperty("url", "");
       this.name = props.getProperty("name", "");
   }

   // getters from interface
}

public class SpringConfig {

   private final String url;
   private final String name;

   public SpringConfig(String contextPath) {
      ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(contextPath);
      this.url = (String) ctx.getBean("url");
      this.name = (String) ctx.getBean("name");
   }

   // getters from interface
}
```

Etc., you could provide a bunch of strategies obviously.

```
public class Application {
   private final Config config;

   public Application(Config config) {
      this.config = config;
   }

   public String doWork() {
      return Client.url(config.getUrl()).get();
   }
}
```